# A node can't have more than one parent in the DOM; how to circumvent this?

Tags: javascript, dom

Say I am building a Todo app with a folder feature (I can store Todos in folders).

So I have a class:

```
class Folder{
    constructor(){
        this.title = "new folder";
        this.element = document.createElement("li"); // element that will show up in the Folder menu bar
        this.dropdownElement = document.createElement("li"); // element that will show up in EACH Todo box
     }
}
```

So, every time I create a new `Folder`, I want to append the `dropdownElement` inside ALL the Todo elements that exist currently, so the user can select which folder the Todo goes to.

```
class Todo{
    constructor(){
        this.element = document.createElement("div"); // the todo box
    }

    static addNewFolderToDropdown(dropdownFolderElement){ 
        for(let todo of Todo.instances){ // loops through all the Todos the user has
            this.element.appendChild(dropdownFolderElement);
        }
    }
}
```

HOWEVER, here is the problem: the `dropdownFolderElement` can only have ONE parent node, so it can't be in every Todo box, only one.

So I tried this:

```
    static addNewFolderToDropdown(dropdownFolderElement){
        for(let todo of Todo.instances){
            const clone = dropdownFolderElement.cloneNode(true);
            this.element.appendChild(clone);
        }
    }
```

It works great! However, what if the user changes the title of the `Folder`? Or what if the user deletes the `Folder`? How will the clone know of such change?

I have been trying to come up with a simple solution but I just can't find a way.

Comment: This is why you should create a model of the content. Store the Todos in a data structure, clone the view nodes, update the model, and when removing a Todo, you can find all the nodes using the stored data.

Comment: @Teemu thanks so much for your answer! you mean Folder, right? so I should create an array with all the clones, and when the user edits the Folder's title, or deletes it, I iterate over all the clones, correct?

Comment: Something like that, maybe even an object reflecting the folder structure and having methods for renaming and deleting and what ever tasks you're performing on the items.

Comment: @Teemu I did that; however, when I edit a single folder's title, it edits all the folders' dropdown elements' title... I think that when I push a clone to the array, in the end they are all the same. Should I be cloning the last clone?

Comment: @Teemu never mind, silly mistake! It worked... thanks!